# How does express-validator prevent this function call from happening?

Tags: javascript, express, middleware, express-validator

This is straight out of the `express-validator` documentation. I noticed that when these functions are passed as middleware, they include arguments and parenthesis, in which case they should be called at runtime right?

```
// ...rest of the initial code omitted for simplicity.
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

app.post(
  '/user',
  // username must be an email
  body('username').isEmail(),
  // password must be at least 5 chars long
  body('password').isLength({ min: 5 }),
  (req, res) => {
    // Finds the validation errors in this request and wraps them in an object with handy functions
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    User.create({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password,
    }).then(user => res.json(user));
  },
);
```

I jumped into the [source code](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/tree/master/src) to try and figure out how they are preventing the function calls, but it is a little over my head. The reason I wanted to learn about this was I was interested in creating a middleware that worked in a similar fashion, where arguments could be passed without actually calling the function at runtime.

Comment: At a basic level they are just functions that return middleware functions. The outer function can take arguments such as these validation functions that can be used by the inner middleware function. This would be a more effective/beneficial question if you shared the middleware you are trying to specially create and what issues you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to reverse engineer some specific code, but will explain how to achieve this in general.

See [the documentation for middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) for reference.

An endpoint is a function that takes two arguments. The request and the response. They are typically named `req` and `res`.

Middleware takes three arguments. The third is `next` which is called to pass control to the next function.

> ```
> app.use(function (req, res, next) {
>   console.log('Time:', Date.now())
>   next()
> })
> ```

Now, middleware doesn't **have** to pass control to the next function. It can just respond.

```
const middleware = (req, res, next) => {
    if (typeof req.body?.username === 'undefined') {
        // No username was provided
        res.send("Error: No username was provided");
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

Now you might want this to be reusable for arguments other than `username`, so you can write a factory function which returns the middleware function.

```
const createMiddleware = (propertyName) => {

    const middleware = (req, res, next) => {
        if (typeof req.body?.[propertyName] === 'undefined') {
            // No value was provided for the propertyName
            res.send(`Error: No ${propertyName} was provided`);
        } else {
            next();
        }
    }

    return middleware;

}
```

And then use it:

```
app.use( createMiddleware('username') );
app.use( createMiddleware('password') );
```